# Set image and title for bar button item?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift2

I currently have a custom navigation controller with bar button items that are simply text buttons. Is it possible to keep the title of the bar button items but also set them as images (icon image + title underneath).

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController
{
    var mode: NavigationMode = .Swipe {
        didSet {
            self.setButtonAttributes()
        }
    }

    private var leftBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    private var middleBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    private var rightBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    private var rightBarButton2: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func configureNavigationItem(navigationItem: UINavigationItem)
    {
        //Configure the bar buttons text and actions


        if (self.leftBarButton == nil) {
            self.leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Menu1", style: .Plain,target: self, action: "menu1Pressed:")
        }
        if (self.middleBarButton == nil) {
            self.middleBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Games", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "gamesPressed:")
        }
        if (self.rightBarButton == nil) {
            self.rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Menu3", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "menu3Pressed:")
        }
        if (self.rightBarButton2 == nil) {
            self.rightBarButton2 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Settings", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "settingsPressed:")
        }

        self.setButtonAttributes()

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [self.leftBarButton, self.middleBarButton, self.rightBarButton, self.rightBarButton2]

    }
```

Updated:

```
  let button = UIButton(type: .System)
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "play"), forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitle("Play", forState: .Normal)
        button.sizeToFit()

        leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)

        if (self.leftBarButton == nil) {
            self.leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Play", style: .Plain,target: self, action: "Pressed:")
        }
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can create UIButton instance, set an image and a title for it, and then create your UIBarButtonItem with it:

```
    let button = UIButton(type: .System)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "YourImage"), forState: .Normal)
    button.setTitle("YourTitle", forState: .Normal)
    button.sizeToFit()
    self.leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

To add an action:

```
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.someAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

where self.someAction is

```
func someAction() {

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question. How can I assign the action to it as well?

Comment: Worked great. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to place the button title below the button's image?

Comment: @OlgaNesterenko When I use your solution, the image is in blue. How do I make the image appear as is, without being turned blue?

Comment: @ShinehahGnolaum try changing second line to `button.setImage(UIImage(named: "YourImage").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), forState: .Normal)`

Answer (score 13):

Create an UIButton, set an image and a title for it and use it as a custom image to init your `UIBarButtonItem(customView:)` with it.

If you want the image to be on the right side of the button, you can set the button's `semanticContentAttribute` to `.forceRightToLeft`.

Swift 4 example:

```
let view = UIView()
let button = UIButton(type: .system)
button.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "DocumentsIcon"), for: .normal)
button.setTitle("Documents", for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openDocuments), for: .touchUpInside)
button.sizeToFit()
view.addSubview(button)
view.frame = button.bounds
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: view)
```

Comment: Please explain your lines of code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Swift 3:

```
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "categories_icon"), for: .normal)
    button.setTitle("Categories", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showCategories), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.sizeToFit()
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```