# Unable to set title for custom bar button?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I have added one custom bar button in my app.I want to set it's title but i am not able to set its title.I am using below code in swift 3.Please advice the best solution.

```
let customButton=UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height:30))
customButton.backgroundColor=Constant.Color.customBlue
customButton.titleLabel?.text = "Add"
customButton.titleLabel?.textColor=UIColor.white
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView:customButton)
barButton.title="Add"
barButton.tintColor=UIColor.white
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=barButton
```

Comment: `UIButton` has a `setTitle` method, you need to use that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316352/increase-navigationbar-height/40320225#40320225

Comment: In addition, don't change attributes for barButton, because are ignored when you initialize UIBarButtonItem with customView.

Comment: if you don't mind can you check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730787/set-image-and-title-for-bar-button-item

Answer (score 3):

You need to set title as below :

```
 customButton?.setTitle("Add", for:.normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this:

```
[customButton setTitle:@"Add" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This code:**

**Note:** This is a better approach to  apply barButton to your **navigationBar** with action.

```
 navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .plain, target: self, action:  #selector(addTapped))

 func addTapped() {
    //Do your stuff here. After Add button pressed
    print("Add Button Pressed")
 }
```

If you still want to use your code.Add the following code to set title to your button as **KKRocks** answer.

```
  customButton?.setTitle("Add", for:.normal)
```