# Customise tool bar item with label and image?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to do a custom toolbar that shows image and label but changes according to which view it is in. I have scoured the internet and read and tried everything I could find on the subject.

I figured that putting a tab bar was not a solution since it can't change for every view (or can it?).

Last time I asked I was marked duplicate and quoted [Set image and title for bad button item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730787/set-image-and-title-for-bar-button-item). I tried that but I could not get that to work at all. Ideally, I wanted a storyboard solution.

I'll show what I have done and tried with so far. What am I doing wrong? Have I missed something? I can't get the title to show on the toolbar item.

Xcode main.storyboard current toolbar version:
[image: Xcode main.storyboard version]

Sketch version (what I want it to look like):
[image]

What I hope it will change to in subsequent view:
[image]

Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {    

@IBOutlet weak var toolbar: UIToolbar!

@IBOutlet weak var leftBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!
var middleBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!
var rightBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!
var rightBarButton2: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let view = UIView()
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "IconHelp"), for: .normal)
    button.setTitle("Help", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(about), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.sizeToFit()
    view.addSubview(button)
    view.frame = button.bounds
//        var items = self.toolbar.items
//        items![0] = UIBarButtonItem(customView: view)
    leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I've tried to solve this all week. :P

Comment: I hope this solve your problem.                  
 https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/RaisedCenterTabBar    https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/center-button-in-tab-bar

Comment: @CrazyPro007 Thanks for that. Looks interesting!

Comment: Happy to hear that answer looks interesting. Can you please rate this answer.

Comment: Hopefully, there's something that's a little more recently supported out there. I'll rummage around. :)